Writing sums as integrals
There are many proofs of the Basel problem (see this wonderful thread Different ways to prove $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$ (the Basel problem)), many of which require a step writing either $\log (1-x)$ or $1/(1-x)$ as their power series to go from the sum $\sum 1/n^2$ to an integral.
Is there a way to go from the sum to an integral without using these power series representations, but rather writing the sum directly as an integral? By "writing a sum as integral" I mean calculus-first-course-style things like $$\lim _{N\rightarrow \infty }\frac {1}{N}\sum _{n=1}^N\frac {1}{1+n/N}=\int _0^1\frac {dx}{1+x}.$$

Are you specifically asking about trying to recognize the Basel problem as a Riemann sum?

ye... is it for some reason clearly not possible or a non-sensible request?

If it were possible, Euler would have discovered it. More seriously, there may be a positive answer to your question but I'm pretty sure it would be quite complicated, more than the answers you linked to.

ye sure i'd not expect it to be any simpler because it would already been written down, but i thought i'd check if there isn't something not too much more complicated than the power series stuff

\begin{align}\lim _{N\rightarrow \infty }\frac {1}{N}\sum _{n=1}^{N-1}\frac {\ln\left(\frac{n}{N}\right)}{n/N-1}=\int _0^1\frac {\ln xdx}{x-1}=\zeta(2)\end{align}

@FDP here the second equality uses the power series for $1/(1-x)$ which is exactly what i'm trying to avoid

If you are looking for a Riemann sum take in account:
$$I=\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\left(\frac{1}{x^2}-\frac{1}{\sin^2{x}} \right)dx=-\frac{2}{\pi}\tag{1}.$$
Consider the partition: $P_{n}=\frac{\pi k}{2n}$ then $I$ can be rewritten as:
$$\lim_{n}\left(\pi\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{n(\cos{(\frac{\pi k}{n}})-1)}+\frac{2n}{\pi}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k^2}\right)=-\frac{2}{\pi}\tag{2}.$$
Or which is the same:
$$\frac{\pi^2}{2}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{n^2(1-\cos{(\frac{\pi k}{n}}))} \sim \sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k^2} \tag{3}.$$
So to solve the Basel problem is enough to show that.
$$\lim_{n}\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{(1-\cos(\frac{\pi k}{n}))}=\frac{1}{3}\tag{4}.$$
This can be solved following Spivak's calculus book.
Updated
It can be proven by induction that (check it):
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{(1-\cos(\frac{\pi k}{n}))}=\frac{2n^2+1}{6}\tag{5},$$
then using $(5)$ we can conclude $(4)$ and the Basel problem.

which part of spivak? (i'll read your answer more carefully in a moment...)

@tomos I don't remember well but if you search on the Basel problem Spivak evaluates a limit like $(4)$ and proves the famous identity.

@tomos I've updated it.

ah sorry for not getting back to you... thanks for this answer!
